# How does the padded_shape works in Keras?

Tags: keras, tf.keras

```
padded_shapes = ([None], ())
train_batches = train_data.shuffle(1000).padded_batch(10, padded_shapes=padded_shapes)
test_batches = test_data.shuffle(1000).padded_batch(10, padded_shapes=padded_shapes)
train_batch, train_labels = next(iter(train_batches))
print(train_batch.numpy())
```

This is from this example:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word_embeddings

Regarding this:

```
padded_batch(10, padded_shapes=padded_shapes)
```

What's the actual padded sequence length? I debug into the code a few times and each time the shape of train_batch is different, although the batch_size is always 10.

The  padded_shapes = ([None], ()) is initialized empty.